# Move zeros to the end of an Array

Tags: scala

Im trying to solve below problem in scala

```
Input:[1,0,44,55,0,43,78,99]
output:[1,44,55,43,78,99,0,0]
```

here is what i have tried

```
def moveZeros(nums:Array[Int]): Array[Int] ={
    for(i<-0 until nums.length ; j<-0 until nums.length){
      if(nums(j)!=0)
      {
        var temp:Int = nums(i)
        nums(i)=nums(j)
        nums(j)=temp
      }

    }
    nums
  }
```

output :[0,0,1,44,55,78,99,43]

not expected output

Im looking for o(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity solution

This is a leetcode problem
https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/

Comment: Any reason you're using what is basically a nested for loop? If you want to do something like bubblesort, you'd just need one index. Then you could swap with the next number if the number at that index was 0, or just keep moving otherwise. (Btw, this is far from idiomatic Scala)

Comment: @Anatolii yes thats right

Comment: Do you really need to use **Arrays** do you really need a mutable solution? Do you really need an efficient solution? - BTW, do you actually need to move the zeros at the en? That sounds more like you want to filter them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez updated my quesion

Comment: @shiv455 I think I have mentioned you this before but anyways, **leetcode** is not a good place for learning **Scala**. All these problems are meant to be implemented in a fully imperative and mutable way, there is no point in using **Scala** just like that. Also, most of the time in real life you do not care that much about the complexity of each function in you code. It is always most important that the code is easier to understand and change over performance. When performance is important _(meaning you already benchamarked and identified the bootlneck)_ then you focus on that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Sure , as im preparing for interview the requirement of the problem is to adhere with given Time & space complexity

Comment: @shiv455 are you preparing for an interview for a Scala position or for a programming position in general? If the first, as I have said before, your code is not idiomatic; and thus it probably won't pass. If the second, it would be good to know which languages / technologies they use, because if they expect performant solutions to thus kind of problems and focus on O-Complexity, they probably aren't using Scala.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that:

```
nums.zipWithIndex
   .sortBy(t => if (t._1 == 0) Int.MaxValue else t._2)
   .map(_._1)
```

[`zipWithIndex`](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-zipwithindex-create-for-loop-counters-scala-cookbook/) will map your collection into sequence of tuples of element value and it's index (i.e. `[(1, 0), (0, 21), (44, 2)]` for start of your example array)

`sortBy` will perform the ordering by either index of element or `Int.MaxValue`

`map` will return map to the original element.

Comment: can you please explain this ?

Comment: also does this satisfies Timecomplexity:O(n) and space:O(1) ? as i know zipwithIndex will create new collection with indexes , i might be wrong

Comment: @shiv455 explained. No, it will not satisfy this requirements, but you should mention them in question if you have them. Also your code in question will not satisfy `O(n)`, it will be `O(n*n)`.

Answer (score 2):

i have rewritten my code with while loop it seems to work, lemme know if there is more elegant solution which satisfies linear time complexity and constant space complexity

```
  def moveZeros(nums: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    while ( {
      i < nums.length && j < nums.length
    }) {
      if (nums(j) != 0) {
        val tmp = nums(i)
        nums(i)=nums(j)
        nums(j) = tmp
        i+=1
      }

      j += 1
    }
    nums

  }
```

Comment: A pretty good example of using the Scala language to write C code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure FP solution with O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.

Unlike any of the other solutions so far, it can work for very large input that doesn't fit in memory:

```
object MoveZeros extends App {
  def moveZerosToEnd(input: Iterator[Int]): Iterator[Int] = {
    val endOfInputSignal = None
    val iteratorWithEndSignal: Iterator[Option[Int]] =
      input.map(Some(_)) ++ Iterator.single(endOfInputSignal)
    iteratorWithEndSignal.scanLeft((0, Iterator.empty[Int])) {
      case ((zerosCounter, _), value) => value match {
        case Some(value) =>
          if (value == 0)
            // Count zero and drop it
            (zerosCounter + 1, Iterator.empty)
          else
            (zerosCounter, Iterator.single(value))
        case None =>
          // Add counted zeros to the end
          (zerosCounter, Iterator.fill(zerosCounter)(0))
      }
    }.flatMap(_._2)
  }
  val input = List(1,0,44,55,0,43,78,99)
  val expected = List(1,44,55,43,78,99,0,0)
  val res = moveZerosToEnd(input.iterator)
    .toList // To list only for easy testing
  assert(res == expected)
  println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional and immutable solution, also very simple to understand:

```
def moveZerosToEnd(input: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
    val ZERO = 0
    val zeroCount = input.count(_==ZERO)
    val removeZeros = input.filter(_!=ZERO)
    val zeroSuffix = Seq.fill(zeroCount)(ZERO)
    removeZeros ++ zeroSuffix
}
```

[image]

**Time complexity: `O(n)`**: Fixed number of iterations over the sequence.
**Space complexity: `O(n)`**: `removeZeros`, `zeroSuffix` and the output line may consume up to `n` space, so complexity is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the immutable, functional, "true Scala" way of doing it in the above answers. But, considering the O(N) time-complexity and O(1) space complexity nothing beats a mutable, efficient, in-place algorithm!

Here is the implementation with Scala's array using `foldLeft`:

```scala
val arr = Array(1, 0, 44, 55, 0, 43, 78, 99)
val lastNonZero = arr.foldLeft(0) { 
  (zeros, elem) => if (elem != 0) { arr(zeros) = elem; zeros+1 } else zeros
}

(lastNonZero until arr.length).foreach{ i => arr(i) = 0 }
```

No extra space due to collection creation (not even `.toList`/`.toArray`) and no sorting.

[image]